# Using sed to enclose matches in double quotes

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to extract headers from emails and create a JSON fragment from them.  I'm using sed to pull out the keys and values, but it's failing to put the trailing quote on each of the lines:

```
$ cat email1 | grep -i -e "^subject:" -e "^from:" -e "^to:" | \
    sed -n 's/\^([^:]*\):[ ]*\(.*\)$/"\1":"\2"/gp'

"From":"Blah Blech <blah.blech@blahblech.com>
"To":"foo@bar.com
"Subject":"Yeah
```

I don't understand why the replacement pattern isn't working.

Comment: I'm guessing it's working fine, but your input has DOS carriage returns on each line.  Try `dos2unix` or one of the other solutions to this massive FAQ.

Comment: Also avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: You're right.. it's carriage returns.  Stripping those allows sed to do it's thing.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, your first group parenthesis is not escaped (which can be avoided by -r), the `g` suffix is useless since there can only be one match per line.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers (click the big hollow checkmark near the votes so it turns solid green) so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping the carriage returns as @tripleee suggested fixed the issue with sed (using ctrl-v ctrl-m to capture the literal carriage return):

```
$ cat email1 | tr -d '^M' | grep -i -e "^subject:" -e "^from:" -e "^to:" | \
    sed -n 's/^\([^:]*\):[ ]*\(.*\)$/"\1":"\2"/gp'

"From":"Blah Blech <blah.blech@blahblech.com>"
"To":"foo@bar.com"
"Subject":"Yeah"
```

Comment: You still have a useless `cat`. You can avoid it with e.g. `tr -d '^M' <email1`.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
 $ awk -F": *" -vOFS=":" -vq="\"" 'tolower($0)~/^from|to|subject/
                                   {print q$1q,q$2q}' email1
```

which combines `cat` or `grep` steps as well.